# Java parameter with undefined type

Tags: java, parameters

In python you don't have to specify the type of a function parameter. 
Is there a way to do this for a Java method parameter? If say I'm not sure what kind of argument will be input.

Comment: Java is a strongly typed language. No. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html - using Generics you can specify the type when calling, but you still have to specify the type: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: What's your _real_ problem? I have never found a case where weak typing has a point (besides saving a few typing).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this with object or generics:

object:

```
public void foo(Object bar)
{

}
```

generics:

```
public <T> void foo(T bar) {

}
```

---

Comment: The former is horrible advice, and is useless because you then still have to know the type inside the method and cast appropriately; in fact one of the reasons Generics were created was to do away with it in many cases, and in most ofter cases polymorphism is the right way to deal with it. The latter you still have to specify the type when calling the method / constructing the object.

Comment: Of course. But on question I can't recognize which case of problem it is. So that are the possibilities...

Comment: While Brian has a point in a complex scenario, I find the 1st perfectly fine - preferable, actually - when it's something as simple as just a method parameter.

Comment: Thanks, the 1st works for me. Basically I just wanted a method that could either take in a String or an Integer.

Comment: Then I think better solution would be to create two methods `public void foo(String bar){ ... }` and `public void foo(int bar){ ... }`. If it solves your problem you can mark it as resolved :)

Answer (score 2):

Python, JavaScript and similar dynamically typed languages have objects that have arbitrary attributes, for example you may code:

```
someObj.someAttr
```

And it will return the attribute value if the type has such an attribute and it's been set, or a null otherwise.

The closest thing to this in java is a Map with String keys and Object values, so try this:

```
public void someMethod(Map<String, Object> map) {
    Object o = map.get("someAttr");
    // do something with o, which may be null
}
```